# The code is duplicated when getting values from CSV with С# CSVHELPER

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

The code is duplicated in the method when reading CSV. How to remove duplicates and why do they occur? Writing to CSV occurs without them, but when reading, duplicates begin:

Method:

```
public class Program
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Product(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Research();
    }

    public static void Research()
    {

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(products);
            }

            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
            { 
            Delimiter = ",",
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Header.ToLower()
            };

            using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))

            {
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Product>();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{record.Id} {record.Name}");
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output to the console:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the csv itself?

Comment: I do not know how to do it better. Should I send a screenshot?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] -- code and CSV data **as text** that we can use to reproduce your problem?  Please do not share the CSV or any other textual data as a screen shot, see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812) for why.

Comment: How do you create your `products`? I'm guessing the issue is there.  I can create a list of products and your code works just fine without any duplicates.

Comment: @OttoRahn depends on how sensitve data is. You can just upload it as a gist on github for example.

Comment: @DavidSpecht I added the code to Pastebin because Overflow does not allow adding new lines of code https://pastebin.com/EuHazZH9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have included the writing and reading of the CSV file in your loop that is creating the products.  Your first product is created, it is written to the CSV file and then it is read and printed to your Console.  The loop continues and your second product is created. Product 1 and product 2 are written to the CSV file and then they are both read from the CSV file and printed to your Console.  This continues for each product that is created, which is why you are showing the duplicates in your console.  You need to close your `for` loop before you write to `file.csv`

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var element = xmlDoc.Item(i);
    var id = int.Parse(element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value);
    var name = element.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
    var product = new Product(id, name);
    //Console.WriteLine($"Id: {id}, name: {name}");

    products.Add(product);

} // Close your loop here!!

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(products);
}
```